# Shiny server LDAP not properly including OU in DN

Tags: ldap, shiny, openldap, shiny-server, ldap-query

I am setting up a Shiny Server w/ LDAP authentication.  My users are organized into departments for administrative purposes.  User DNs use the following format:

```
uid=testuser1,ou=People,ou=Dept1,dc=example,dc=com
uid=testuser2,ou=People,ou=Dept2,dc=example,dc=com
```

My issues is that I can seem to find a setting that will allow both of the above users to login.  When the users attempts to login, the DN used needs to have the department (e.g. ou=Dept1) included, but it will instead try to bind without it (e.g. uid=testuser2,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com).

Is there a way to set up the conf file so that shiny will search for the full DN (including department) of the user with a given UID and then bind using that full DN?

I get the sense that this is possible from the [shiny configuration reference](http://rstudio.github.io/shiny-server/latest/), but I can't seem to find the right settings.

In particular, this passage seems relevant, but It isn't clear to me what I need to do for this use case:

> **4.6.9 user_filter**
>
> Some systems (notably many Active Directory implementations) do not
>   use the username as a part of the user's DN. In such systems, It may
>   be necessary to perform an extra LDAP query after binding to determine
>   the user's DN based on their username before group membership can be
>   determined. This setting stores the LDAP filter used to find the user
>   object which matches the entered username.
>
> Using the default provided for auth_active_dir
>   (userPrincipalName={userBind}), as an example. Shiny Server Pro will
>   attempt to bind to the LDAP server using the given username (after
>   being manipulated as defined in user_bind_template) and password. If
>   successful, it will then search for an object whose attribute
>   userPrincipalName matches the username manipulated by
>   user_bind_template. If found, the returned object's DN will be made
>   available to the group_filter as the {userDN} variable.
>
> Default Value
>
> ```
> For auth_ldap -- N/A
> For auth_active_dir -- userPrincipalName={userBind}
> ```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Side comment: your directory is poorly set up. You shouldn't model the organizational structure in the DIT. If a user changes departments, or if the departments themselves are reorganized, you have to reorganize your tree. You should have users under a Users subtree, and departments under a Departments subtree, and use *attributes* to inter-relate them.

Comment: To be clear, the directory setup is not of my own choosing.  This is default behavior of the software used to manage the directory (Gosa: https://oss.gonicus.de/labs/gosa/).  In any case, this limitation does not affect my use case.  The "departments" are such that department changes would be very infrequent and it would be easy enough, even preferable, to generate new accounts in such cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting w/ Rstudio technical support, I was able to get it working with the following config in Shiny Server:

```
auth_ldap ldaps://server:636/dc=example,dc=com {
   base_bind "uid=searcheraccount,ou=People,{root}"  'thepassword';
   user_filter "uid={username}";
   user_search_base "";
}
```

What this does:

1. It uses a double bind.  That is, when shiny-server contacts the ldap
   server, it first authenticates with a specified account
   `uid=searcheraccount,ou=people,{root}` using its password `thepassword`.
2. Once in, it searches for the dn of the account with with
   `uid={username}` (i.e. the username entered by the user on the login
   page).  In this case, this should return something like
   `uid=testuser1,ou=People,ou=Dept1`
3. It binds with this dn+root.

I had tried setups similar to this, but the problem was in `user_search_base`.  In my previous setup, I had set this parameter to be 'ou=people', which fails since my users in departments are not directly under `ou=people,{root}`.

This configuration also would have solved a related problem I had previously when gosa was setting up accounts where the DNs were constructed using {firstName}&" "&{lastName} rather than the uid.